# Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, .net-4.0, json.net

I'm trying to do some json deserialization on windows phone 7, so I decided to use Newtonsoft.json library, because it seems to support this platform also. Unfortunatelly I'm stuck with these errors:

```
Error 1 Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported
```

and

```
Error 4 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?
```

I found out that I can't just add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` (VS tells me that it wasn't built with Windows Phone runtime) in my project, so what else can be done? I used newtonsoft lib from portable+net40+sl4+wp7+wp8 and then from sl4-windowsphone71 folders in the library. Nothing works.

Comment: Was Json.NET installed via NuGet?

Comment: Yes, it was installed via NuGet

Comment: Is it a new project? are you running Visual Studio 2012 with Update 4? also, make sure Nuget itself is up to date.

Comment: Well, it's a new project for me :). I'm using VS 2010, and nuget 2.7.

Comment: It's VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone, actually.

Comment: I can't confirm that Json.NET works on VS 2010 but it should. I do know that it works with VS 2012 or 2013. If you're only starting with Windows Phone, you should look at VS 2013 + WP8 as WP7 development in being phased out (VS 2013 supports it, VS 2013 doesn't).

Comment: Yeah, but I guess that to install VS 2013 I need Windows 8, right? If so it's out of the question right now. I know that Json.NET works with VS 2010, because I already used it, but in Web Developer version and for web projects I can add reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll (or is it there by default?)

Comment: When adding from NuGet, it should be setup properly so there shouldn't be any need to change any references. Very strange.

Comment: try to download the build directly from the web site https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/113546 there where some problems with NuGet package for json.net recently.

Comment: I actually downloaded json.net from here directly: https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/82120 . It still won't work. I don't know, maybe I'm doing something wrong? The dll from portable+net40+sl4+wp7+wp8 is the one I should use?

Comment: It would be good to see the code you're using to deserialize.  Are you using JObject and dynamic types?

Answer (score 2):

This error relates to dynamic types.  Try using the JSON.NET generic methods, with which you specify the deserialization type, instead of the method which returns a dynamic type.

i.e. Don't do this...

http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/

Do this...

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx